# Button to Export Range to New Google Sheets

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom Character Sheet I built in Google Sheets.  Among the tabs I also have some custom tools I've built to create items.

I would like to be able to export the items created to a new Google Sheet after creating the item in the main sheet.

Basically, I would like to create a button that when clicked, it copies the values (not the formula) from a certain range into a new Google Sheet.

The button, when clicked, would have the following tasks:

1. Create a new Google Sheet with the name of {Cell A1}
2. Copies/Exports Cell Range Values (not formula) {A1:G25} to the new Google Sheet it created in #1 above.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

For clickable scripts you've got two options; use a Drawing to draw a button, and you can set a script to run on click. Otherwise, using the [UI class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui), you can add a menu that can run a script.

As far as new sheet creation, you'll be using [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)) or [create(name,rows,colums)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String,Integer,Integer)).

In order to pull values, you'll simply use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) in the [RANGE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class. If you do end up needing it to pull a formula, you can use [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas).